# Process.Start() works in interactive but not in debug or execution via terminal

Tags: c#, .net-core, f#

I'm trying to start VS Code via `Process.Start("code")` which gives me a `Win32Exception` saying the file cannot be be found. However, if I execute that code in C# or F# interactive VS Code launches properly. I've also checked the PATH variable during debugging and it contains the directory of the *code.cmd* file so it should be found. Interestingly, if I change `Process.Start("code")` to `Process.Start("code.cmd")` interactive still works normally, but it crashes the debugger / terminal that started my application.

Why is interactive behaving differently?

Comment: Why just don't `Process.Start(@"C:\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe")`?

Comment: @GuruStron I could do that, but that doesn't answer my question. Besides that, the application might not be installed in the same directory. For example, your path of the code.exe isn't the same on my system.

Comment: Set `UseShellExecute` to `false`, you'll need to use `Start(ProcessStartInfo)` overload. See if that solves your problem.

Comment: @InBetween interesting. It works if I set it to `true` but it throws the exception if set to `false`.

Comment: @Timo woops sorry, meant that to be `true`. net core default is `false` (while NET Framework apps default is `true`). When its set to `false` you can only start executables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.cmd files are Windows script files, not executables. In order to start a process via a non executable file you need to set `UseShellExecute` to `true`.

In NET core apps, the default value for `UseShellExecute` is `false` while in .NET Framework apps, its `true`. That could be the reason why you are seeing different behavior with C# Interactive.